# Accented characters in search text not preserved consistently in suggestions

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just searched for **in trockenen Tüchern**, which yielded no results. The first suggestions were:

> - Place your search terms in quotes to search for a phrase:
>     [**"in trockenen Tchern"**](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22in+trockenen+Tchern%22)
> - Search within a specific set of tags:
>     **[tag] in trockenen tüchern**
>     **[tag] [another-tag] in trockenen tüchern**

The **ü** in the search text has been preserved in the “tag search” suggestion but not in the “phrase” suggestion.

Comment: @Oded: The issue seems to be moot now anyway, since there are no longer any suggestions presented when a search yields no results.

Answer (score 2):

The tag engine has been completely replaced a while ago.

When searching for **in trockenen Tüchern** on Meta, this question is returned.